# Please could someone help with a Matrices question?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, matrices, functions

I already know that $I$ stands for the identity matrix. I understand all other matrices question from the textbook, but this question truly puzzles me. Please could you make it understandable for a younger child. Thanks.

Let

$$\pmatrix{3& 2\\-1&2}\pmatrix{x& -2\\1&3}=kI$$

Find k and x.

Comment: I deleted most of what you'd written, since it was irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Let's start here -- what's "the textbook?"

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You can find help on formatting math for this site [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Also, please be more careful with your tags.  "matrices" is the only one that actually applies to this post.  Do you know how to multiply matrices?

Comment: It is called AQA Further Maths A level. Ngl I am actually 11 years old doing A level maths (AP maths, America, I think). I can show you my passport that I am actually 11 years old and is not a kid just wanting homework answers, otherwise I would take a picture and upload it to Stack Exchange, which is just plain dirty.

Comment: @saulspatz, yes I do know how to multiply matrices, if it 2x4 matrix and 4x2 matrix they can multiply each other.

Comment: Nobody is questioning your age.  Just tell us what you know about the problem so we can give you an appropriate answer.  How far can you get with the question?

Comment: These are two $2\times2$ matrices.  What is their product?

Comment: If I had (2,2) - top and (3,3) - bottom, multipled by (7,2), I would multiply the 7 by the top matrix to get 14, 14 (top) and 6, 6 (bottom). Then I add them all up to get (20, 20)

Comment: @saulspatz. Everything else in matrices is relatively simple, but I do not understand how to reformat everything from a matrix to a simultaneous equation. Do you know any website links, that could help me refine this part of matrices. Also the identity matrix is I = (1,0) - top and then (0,1) - bottom

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying.  Please format these as matrices.  If you right-click on one of the matrices, you can choose "Show math as.. TeX commands" from the pop-up and you will see how to format a matrix.  Remember to enclose the matrix in `$` signs.

Comment: @ThePointer It is hard to explain on computer. Could I just upload a video to get the necessary help. I am not a beggar in any way.

Comment: @JieGao You can just right-click on the matrices already posted (in your question and in Leaning's answer) and copy the code and edit it with your own values. Right-click this: $\pmatrix{3& 2\\-1&2}\pmatrix{x& -2\\1&3}= ?$, select "Show Math As" and then "TeX commands".

Comment: I do not see the TeX commands on screen. Where is it located?

Comment: @JieGao Use LaTeX to format your matrices; otherwise, we cannot understand what you're trying to convey to us. Make sure you understand how to multiply matrices.

Comment: Thanks @thepointer, I was wondering are you a maths tutor by any chance. Just wanted one, so I could become next Terence Tao ☺

Comment: @thepointer I do not understand this fancy stack exchange stuff. I will just upload a video on matrices, onto my youtube and then attach a link on this website,

Comment: @JieGao No, that's a waste of time. The next Terence Tao needs to learn how to use TeX commands first. Right-click the matrix I posted in my comment above and follow the instructions I provided. Copy and paste the TeX command into your own comment and just change the values for yourself. Experiment with it; that's how you'll learn.

Comment: Lol sent a YouTube link @thepointer

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73xQBZvufIc

Comment: @ThePointer always keep to my word

Comment: @JieGao As I thought, it seems that you're misunderstanding matrix multiplication. Pause at 0:07; you should have $$\pmatrix{2 & 0\\ 0 & 2}\pmatrix{1 \\ 1} = \pmatrix{2 \\ 2}$$ You first need to study how to multiply matrices; once you understand that, *then* you can move onto problems such as the one you've posted above.

Comment: Dude, why are you so fussy. It is my scrapbook for rough working out

Comment: Dude, I literally wrote the answer check the video

Comment: @JieGao How am I being fussy? I didn't sit there and check each calculation on each page, but, for the calculation I paused to look at, it seems that you're multiplying matrices incorrectly.

Comment: @JieGao As I said, video is not a good format for this. Learn to use TeX commands.

Comment: @thepointer NGL, why did you check and pause for every question. Of course, there was going to be mistakes, it is only a SCRAPBOOK for rough working out. Geez, chill out dude, not the end of the world. I had multiplied it by 0 instead of 1, only a slight error, probably dyslexia. But anyways, help other individuals, other than me please, for you are a good samaritan! ☺

Comment: @thepointer also, if you had paused the video, you would've seen that I had (2,2) as the corrected answer. You are actually damaging my self esteem, considering I am 11 and you are 35 with a lifetime experience of maths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you already know how to compute the product of two matrices. Then you will be able to obtain the following equality: 
$$\pmatrix{3& 2\\-1&2}\pmatrix{x& -2\\1&3}=\pmatrix{3x+2&0\\-x+2&8}$$
Next step is to solve the equation:

$$\pmatrix{3x+2&0\\-x+2&8}=k\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$$
The equality of this two matrices means the following four equalities:
$$3x+2=k, 0=0, -x+2=0, 8=k$$

Solving this, one gets $k=8$ and $x=2$.

---

If you do not know how to multiply matrix, try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20multiply%202x2%20matrices&oq=how%20to%20multiply%202&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.6292j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).